# Which thread am I supposed to use to call uiManager calls inside a react-native native ui component?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-native-module, react-native-native-ui-component

I'm building a **native UI component** for Android that uses a view that extends a `ReactRootView`.

On the constructor of my view (named `SyncRootView`) if I check the thread I get `Thread curThread = Thread.current(); // main`
so we're on the main thread.

The problem is that if I try to run any `uiManager` calls (for example `uiManager.createView`, I receive that error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.rnexample, PID: 16424
 java.lang.AssertionError
     at com.facebook.infer.annotation.Assertions.assertCondition(Assertions.java:66)
     at com.facebook.react.common.SingleThreadAsserter.assertNow(SingleThreadAsserter.java:27)
     at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ShadowNodeRegistry.getNode(ShadowNodeRegistry.java:67)
     at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:278)
     at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364)
     at com.sudoplz.rnsynchronouslistmanager.Sync.SyncRootView$3.run(SyncRootView.java:177)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

So basically the problem is a class called [SingleThreadAsserter](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26684cf3adf4094eb6c405d345a75bf8c7c0bf88/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/common/SingleThreadAsserter.java#L25) part of `react-native` which I'm not even sure why it's there.
It's `mThread` value is set to `native_module_thread...` therefore I get an `AssertionError` because I'm on the main thread.

If I try to run those `uiManager` calls on the native_module thread (by using `ctx.runOnNativeModulesQueueThread(myRunnable)`), at first it seems to work, but later on (I guess once the module initialisation is over??) I get

```
Tried to enqueue runnable on already finished thread: 'native_modules... dropping Runnable.
02-21 01:55:36.415 17126-17126/com.rnexample W/MessageQueue: Handler (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler) {bda653f} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler) {bda653f} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
     at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
     at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:643)
     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:612)
     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:582)
     at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:338)
     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl.runOnQueue(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:61)
     at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.runOnNativeModulesQueueThread(ReactContext.java:287)
     at com.sudoplz.rnsynchronouslistmanager.Sync.SyncRootView.dispatchInUIThread(SyncRootView.java:516)
     at com.sudoplz.rnsynchronouslistmanager.Sync.SyncRootView.runApplication(SyncRootView.java:188)
     at com.sudoplz.rnsynchronouslistmanager.Sync.SyncRootView.<init>(SyncRootView.java:97)
     at com.sudoplz.rnsynchronouslistmanager.Sync.SyncRootView.<init>(SyncRootView.java:61)
     at com.sudoplz.rnsynchronouslistmanager.List.SPView.<init>(SPView.java:20)
     at com.sudoplz.rnsynchronouslistmanager.SynchronousListManager.createViewInstance(SynchronousListManager.java:37)
     at com.sudoplz.rnsynchronouslistmanager.SynchronousListManager.createViewInstance(SynchronousListManager.java:19)
     at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.createView(ViewManager.java:44)
     at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:224)
     at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:153)
     at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run(UIViewOperationQueue.java:813)
     at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches(UIViewOperationQueue.java:926)
     at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$2100(UIViewOperationQueue.java:47)
     at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:986)
     at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:31)
     at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:136)
     at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:107)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:872)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:618)
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

on the constructor of my `ReactRootView` I did:

`nativeModulesThread = (MessageQueueThreadImpl) ctx.getCatalystInstance().getReactQueueConfiguration().getNativeModulesQueueThread();`
where ctx is the `ReactContext` available to every UI Native component.

Then I created this method:

```
protected void dispatchInAppropriateThread(Runnable runnable) {
    if (runnable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (nativeModulesThread.getLooper().getThread().isAlive()) {
        ctx.runOnNativeModulesQueueThread(runnable);
    } else {
        this.post(runnable);
    }
}
```

so now whenever I need to run a runnable I do:

```
dispatchInAppropriateThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do cool stuff
    }
});
```